# Using Two Different Options for Two Seperate Jssor Sliders on Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I have 2 different types of Jssor sliders on a website. The problem I encounter is setting up 2 different sets of options for each slider. I tried renaming the second variable from options to optionss temporarily but the sliders break and don't run. if I use the same variable of options I have no problem and both work. The problem is I want to run 2 different options as one slider is a gallery and the other is scrolling logos.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Ok I figured it out... make sure you use the naming convention of options1 & var options2 etc... incrementing the numerical value for any additional slide you have on the page...

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("main_header_slider", options1);
var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("content_gallery", options2);
var jssor_slider3 = new $JssorSlider$("footer_banner", options3);
```

Comment: Please post your javascript code here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f2hwheuz/1/